# Separating the coordinates of two or more polygons

Tags: geometry, coordinates, polygon, shapes

I have a list of coordinates that represents two (or potentially more) different polygon corner point coordinates (x,y). How can I separate this list into two (or more) separate lists of separate polygon corner point coordinates? That is, the list above includes coordinates for the red and yellow polygon in the image below. How can I separate between the two?

These polygons do not overlap/intersect.

Example:

Separating this

```
coordslist _of_two_polygons= [(634.196912844544, 573.5518673990564), (634.72, 596.06), (634.04, 612.57), (628.14, 636.73), (619.82, 651.76), (614.85, 661.02), (612.03, 660.08), (613.91, 653.64), (619.01, 639.95), (621.7, 631.76), (623.98, 622.64), (626.53, 608.54), (624.52, 587.34), (624.92, 585.99), (623.5164081989366, 571.5658544699229), (621.28, 571.15), (622.6759134800419, 565.013087688352), (638.1176399986085, 565.552256750043), (637.67, 570.49), (635.37, 573.77), (634.196912844544, 573.5518673990564), (605.9745784899422, 564.4299376691641), (605.05, 565.73), (602.1, 572.04), (598.34, 579.28), (594.99, 583.18), (590.02, 581.3), (593.24, 577.27), (596.5165952802347, 563.3459954757998), (598.53, 564.17), (605.9745784899422, 564.4299376691641), (634.196912844544, 573.5518673990564)]
```

into this

```
 coords_polygon1 = [(..),..,(..)]
    coords_polygon1 = [(..),..,(..)]
```

A visual example to explain a bit: (not exactly the coordinates above, but the logic is the same)

[image]

Comment: Is any list of valid polygons fine? Can they overlap? For instance, if your original list is 6 points in a perfect hexagon, what are the acceptable answers? There's 3 possible answers of two triangles if you don't allow overlap, and 20 if you do.

Comment: @kcsquared Thanks for the comment & apologies for not being more specific before. These polygons never intersect/overlap.

Comment: Question is still unclear. How can one separate two polygons?

Comment: @MBo Added a picture to clarify, hope it helps.

Comment: The answer to the overlap question helps, but that only addresses one of the 3 questions I asked. There may be many valid answers to your question. Please specify what exact output you're looking for, and preferably with a real example that you explain. Also, there are many types of polygons, but your image contains a circle, which is not a polygon by almost all standard definitions.